# Power Bi, Return percentage of grand total but the column's values are text

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to return the percentage of the grand total from #number of clients using the second and fourth columns.  The number of clients values are text and are collected using Count('Table'[Column]).  That is where I have run into issues.  When I try Countrows() or AllSelected() to try and work around it, it returns all the rows and doesn't keep the filters I have set.

My current measures:

Client Total = COUNTA('Table'[Client_Name])

% with at least 1 document = DIVIDE(SUM('Table'[At Least 1 Document Sum]), [Client Total])

Right now, it only calculates the percentage based on the filtered # of clients in the same row versus the grand total.  I am hoping to have it use a dynamic grand total that is shown at the bottom of the table.

[Current Table] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/IG254.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solve

Measure Name = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table'),ALLSELECTED('Table'))

Then:

Measure Name = SUM('Table'[At Least 1 Document Sum])/'Table'[Measure]